# Wordpress permalinks hijacking my custom urls to landing pages

Tags: apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a bunch of `/promo` like urls that go outside the realm of wordpress to a custom php page. But with the default rewrite rules in wordpress, it redirects all requests to its own 404 page.

I would like to be able to redirect `/promo` to `http://domain.com/subdir/index.php?flag1=foo&flag2=bar`. The default wordpress .htaccess is below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit .htaccess yourself and add your redirection rules before WordPress'. If you're not comfortable with directly editing the .htaccess (always save the existing version first!), you can use a plugin like this one:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-htaccess-control/

It lets you add your own redirection rules into the .htaccess ahead of WordPress' rules.